# How to plot the following function?

Tags: plotting

Say I have a function

```
f(x,y,theta,xi) = x*y*c*theta*xi;
```

where `c` is a function of `theta` and `xi` and is predefined as

```
c:=theta*xi+theta^xi^2;
```

so `f` is effectively a function of `x`, `y`, `theta`, `xi`.

when I do the

```
Plot3D[f[x,y,0.5,0.5],{x,0,1},{y,0,1}]
```

Mathematica could not automatically calculate the value of c.

How do I plot a function of this sort?

That is, it contains a parameter which is a expression of the variables.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear how you defined `f`.  How it is done will affect how it works.  Probably, the global variable `theta` in the definition of `c` is not the same as the local parameter `theta` in the definition of `f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `c` an explicit function of `theta` and `xi`

```
c[theta_, xi_] = theta*xi + theta^xi^2;

f[x_, y_, theta_, xi_] = x*y*c[theta, xi]*theta*xi;

Plot3D[f[x, y, 0.5, 0.5],
 {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Bob, thanks for your code. But when I run it, it gives "Tag Times in (theta\ xi)[theta_,xi_] is Protected."I understand that it is because I am passing a function to another function.

Comment: Could you please share your thought on how to overcome this problem- tag times is protected" in general? thanks!

Comment: @LazyGamer - The code as posted works. Clear all of your definitions or start with a fresh kernel.